# How to remove first module errors in Windows

Tags: magento2, module

I've created module in magento 2.

After this, when I tried to run this module, it creates the following errors...

the one is to run command..

this is what it shows when trying to run command

[image]

Please suggest something , how to run command ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows, you need to write command in this way:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12> php.exe -f "c:\wamp\www\magento_test\bin\magento" setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. This is how we do things here. When an answer helps you solve your problem you mark the answer as accepted. And you should not write "thanks" answers. the answers section is for answers only.

Comment: With the "thanks" removed it's a valid answer, as the other answers did not explain how it works in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read the error message.

It clearly says you have to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` in the console.

Comment: Yes, this is a common command you'll need to run when, for example, you install some custom code using the command line or when you upgrade such code.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated question, i'm facing issue regarding running command...

Comment: if you are on windows try with `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. If `php.exe` is not added to the system path you need to try `"C:\path\to\php.exe"  bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

If You looking for other tutorial - follow this link below
http://nirgoldman.com/2015/08/11/magento-2-basic-module-development/

code example can be found at this repo :
https://github.com/refaelgold/Welcome

If the command not run - do

```
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Good luck

Comment: thanks , your link is awesome! i've updated question. suggest me .

Comment: so mark it as "solved" and give me some credit :)